# How can I compute stock yield using an array with data on different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first time to ask a question!

I have an issue with Excel VBA.

I need to compute stock returns using Excel VBA.

I got a data sheet and I need to compute it on the other sheets.

I can bring the values from the data sheet but I never get the order of data.

When I export my code, I only get the last value of the data but need all the values.

Please let me know what is wrong .

**My Code So Far**

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub VolCorrChole()

    Dim w As Object
    Set w = WorksheetFunction
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim KOSPI200() As Variant
    ReDim KOSPI200(0 To 267)
    
    KOSPI200() = Sheets("Adj Index").Range("B4:B270").Value

    Dim yldKOSPI200() As Double
    ReDim yldKOSPI200(0 To 267)

    For i = 1 To 268
        Cells(i + 20, 3) = (KOSPI200(i) / KOSPI200(i - 1)) - 1
    Next

End Sub
```

I expected I could get the stock return by order of its original datasheet.

Comment: Please share some sample data as text and screenshots of the before and after i.e. the source data and the desired result.

Comment: Dim KOSPI200 As Variant then KOSPI200 = Sheets("Adj Index").Range("B4:B270").Value. Delete the redim.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a Range to an Array in Excel needs the following

- **Predifined one-dimensional array**

In this case values can be assigned one-by-one within a loop, something like this

```
Dim arr(0 to 266)
For i=0 to 266

arr(i)=Cells(i+4,2)

Next i
```

- **Assign to a variant**

arr=Range("B4:B270")

In your example the direct assigning results a two-dimensional array (with index range start from 1), from where the values can be get like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub VolCorrChole()

    Dim w As Object
    Set w = WorksheetFunction
    Dim i As Integer

    'Dim KOSPI200() As Variant
    'ReDim KOSPI200(0 To 267)
    
    KOSPI200 = Sheets("Adj Index").Range("B4:B270").Value

    'Dim yldKOSPI200() As Double
    'ReDim yldKOSPI200(0 To 267)

    For i = 1 To 266
        Cells(i + 20, 3) = (KOSPI200(i+1,1) / KOSPI200(i,1)) - 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Remarks:

1. The sizes of the array and the Range not corresponds.
2. In your example when i=268 would cause an error (disregarded the dimensional problem of the assignment, because i is greater than the upper index of the array.

Answer (score 0):

When you populate the variant array `KOSPI200` with values from the sheet range:

```
KOSPI200() = Sheets("Adj Index").Range("B4:B270").Value
```

the array is redimensioned to 2D array according to the size of the range used, in this case `(1 To 267, 1 To 1)`
So your previous `ReDim` statement is without effect.
And then, when you refer to this array you must use two dimensions and proper values of indexes: from 1, not from 0.